# Adding a table of contents to a Microsoft Word Document using vbs

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I am attempting to write a vbs script to create a word document that also contains a Table of Contents.  I am able to insert a Table of Contents but am unable to populate the table.

```
Set oInfo = Dictionary.Items("Use Case")
    For Each oInfo in oInfo

        Set entryRange = objSelection.Range
        objDoc.TablesOfContents.MarkEntry entryRange, oInfo("Name"), oInfo("Name"), W, 1
        objSelection.TypeText "Info" + vbNewline + oInfo("Name")
        objSelection.TypeParagraph()
    Next
objDoc.TablesOfContents.Add(tocRange)
```

This results in the Table of Contents being inserted properly but only displays "**No table of contents entries found.**"  Also, at the end of the document, I get weird unformatted text that looks something like this:
**{TC "Info1" \f C \| "1"}**
This gets repeated for each object that I iterate through in the For loop with the correct title for each section.  I feel like I am on the right track, but I don't know enough about the `TablesOfContents` object to do what I would like to do. I believe one of the main problems is the `TableId` field in the `markEntry` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use MarkEntry, Word inserts a { TC } field. That's what those "weird unformatted text" things are. They do not have a visible result so if you toggle to field results view (Alt-F9 on Windows Word) and do not show hidden text, they will disappear altogether. So they are typically things that would be added after the document is fully populated, at the appropriate places in the document. I would guess that most ToCs actually grab their entries from either Heading levels or Outline levels. If you go into the relevant parts of Word itself and play around with the various ToC options, you should be able to get a better idea of how these things work.

When you insert the TOC, you also get a field. At the monment your code is probably inserting

```
{ TOC \o "1-9" }
```

That will get entries from paragraphs with Outline levels 1-9. But it won't insert entries from the TC fields. For that, you need (at least)

```
{ TOC \f C }
```

(since C is the identifier you are using in yourTC fields.)

You can do that in VBA code using

```
objDoc.TablesOfContents.Add Range:=tocRange, UseFields:=True, TableID:="C"
```

If you still need to bring in entries from the "Outline levels" then you need to set the appropriate parameter in the .Add method to True.

At some point in your code, you may also need to locate the TOC field and "update" it.

As an aside, if you cannot access all the field facilities that you need via the object model's .Add and .MarkEntry fields, it is also possible to insert most field codes more directly, e.g. by adding a field of type "wdFieldEmpty" to a range and providing its field code.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I was able to get the table of contents inserted into my document but now I am trying to get the page numbers correctly displayed.  As of right now all sections of the table of contents display the last page of the document and when I click on one of the entries it takes me to the end of the document where the identifiers: {TC "Info1" \f C \| "1"} are located. I'm not really sure what I need to do signify the end of each entry.

Comment: If you use TC fields, they need to be in the correct place in the document. For example, if your ToC needs to have an entry that says "Look here........2" where 2 is the page number, then the { TC } field needs to be on page 2. So the question then becomes "How should your code decide where your TC fields need to be?" At the moment, I think it is just putting them all where the Selection is.

Comment: I was able to figure it out.  From your comments, I was able to conclude that I didn't NEED to use TC fields.  I was able to set the headings as "Heading 1" style and populate the Table of Contents that way.